# list adapter: get item position without onclick ect

Tags: android, json, listview, adapter, android-volley

I fainaly become able to fetch second json url inside the first url adapter class, but the problem now is like not orginaized i think its because i didnt spicifiy to fetch url2 for each single item by its position, right? If so, how i can fix this, 
Other activities works fine fetching second url but its on item click, meanwhile in this activity im trying to fetch without on click.
Im using volley, inside adapter class, after i get the data from first url model class and set it to its views i call
       fetchurl2(string); before return ConvertView;

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that onItemClicked in the list is returning the incorrect item?

Well I'll give a brief rundown of some of the problems I've encountered and if it sounds like any of them resp.

1. Implementing an onClickListener and retrieving the ID of the view that was clicked in a listview doesn't work properly. It seems sporatic to me but I always had to bypass that functionality.

Solution: implementing onListItemClickListener gives you the position you have clicked so it is not so reliant on Ids (ex: R.id.viewId)

2. The listview constantly changes figures and values making it the incorrect value you have assumed would appear as a result of clicking

Solution: hold object references in an encapsulating BaseAdapter class. I haven't had much experience with Volley but doing it from scratch requires a class extend BaseAdapter and you inflate your own views and populate the data.

3. Ensure you are setting the correct data to pass into your fetch class

This could be as a result of #1s problem and often is but if you are assigning your view controls, ensure they all have their own unique references and are retrieved relative to the view inflated:

```
   //Method inflates a view as part of an implementation of BaseAdapter
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    convertView = inflater.inflater(R.layout.MYVIEW, parent, false);
    //Note the retrieval relative to the view being inflated 
    final TextView tvURL = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvURL);
    tvURL.setText("www.stackoverflow.com");
    tvURL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    fetchURL(tvURL.getText().toString());
    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT

An example adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context = null;
    private ArrayList<CustomItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomItem> items)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //will never exceed position as that has a range of 0 to the size we give
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem);
        TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        ImageView ivFeature = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFeature);
        TextView tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        CustomItem item = items.get(position);
        tvName.setText(item.getName());
        tvDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
        //Call for your item to process a picture into a bitmap then
        ivFeature.setImageBitmap(item.getFeatureImage());
        return convertView;
    }
}

/*
    //Instantiation:
    myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(Activity.this, myItemsList);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myListView.invalidate();

 */
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but now the onclick method works fine in activity A,what i need is in activity B i want the same job "fetch json url" but without OnClick

Comment: If you have the url, you can make a call to it in the convertview method or prepopulate the expected results asynchronously with an AsyncTask

Comment: Yes but that result: some imageviews somtime empty somtime filled, textview same text for all items, some images changing and keep loading other items images

Comment: Did you go with the BaseAdapter solution? I can make you a complete example one if you want

Comment: I dont understand what you mean cuz my adabter extents baseadapter

Comment: If the example for 2urls in one listveiw that will be awesome of you

Comment: I surfed entire web with no luck

Comment: Ops, i told you i dont want it on click thats the problem, look at your first code and imagin    fetchURL(tvURL.getText().toString()); without onclick method,thats what i wanr but it will pubulate every single item with all items text or photos

Comment: You have to know what kind of data you're expecting to be returned. Just like any URL Get call, you assign that data through an input stream and then read the expected return values.